# Getting the largest integer filename in a Wolfram cloud folder?

Tags: files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud

I'm creating a Wolfram function which saves PNGs into a cloud folder called `png`. I'd like this function to save pictures in increments, like

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

each time it's used.  In order to pull this off, I need a way to scan a cloud folder, find the highest integer `*.png` file, and then add one to it for the new one. Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Your will want a combination of `FileNames["*.png", yourWorkingDir]` to get all *.png file names in the working dir, `FileBaseName` to drop the extension, then `ToExpression` to turn the strings to numbers, and `Max` to get the highest, then `ToString` and `FileNameJoin` perhaps to create the new name. Tedious, but all pretty obvious from the docs. Don't know that there is a more direct way.

Comment: @MarcoB Is there an equivalent of `FileNames` that works with cloud files?

Comment: `FileNames` already works on the cloud: try `CloudEvaluate@ FileNames[]`.